# iOS add fixed footer UIView to multiscreen app

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a simple question - is possible to add to an iOS application a simple UIView to the bottom of the app (like a footer view) to be on fixed position all time the app is running? When moving from one screen to another the footer still be there on fixed position? It means the footer is on top z-order and screens are changing under the footer.

The purpose of that footer bar is to show a progress bar of downloading huge amount of data in footer all time the data are downloaded independently on using the app and changing screens using navigation controller.

Any tips how to do that?

Thanks Michal

Comment: You want to show a loader bar, but sounds like you want to add another IOS application

Comment: You can use `UIProgressView` to show progress!

Comment: @KetanParmar Yes, UIProgressView will be included in footer view, as well as other labels and so on. That is not so important. But it is not the question which view to use but HOW to have it all the time as fixed footer when moving from screen to screen?

Comment: You can try `container view` or `horizontal scroll view`or `collection view with single cell`!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your custom UIView to keyWindow with some constraints. EG:

```
let progressView: ProgressView = // Instance from nib or sth
let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow! as UIView
window.addSubview(progressView)

// Add leading constraint between window and progress view
// Add trailing constraint between window and progress view
// Add bottom constraint between window and progress view
// Add height constraint to progress view
```

I think you will need to offset your others views to be over your progress view.

Comment: It sounds like what I am looking for. The key could be the keyWindow :) I am going to try it and let you know. Tx.